# jQuery smooth scroll snippet works with different speed

Tags: jquery, time, distance, smooth-scrolling

Ive got this rather popular code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

And in html:

```
<a href="#scrollThere">Click</a>
```

Goes to

```
<div class="scroll" id="scrollThere"></div>
```

But on one page website when the divs are on different height, i.e. The scroll has to go on different lenghths - the scrolling is sometimes much faster and sometimes very slow. What kind of code would make te scroll always be **time = speed * distance**, not **time = lentgh in ms** or in other words how can I achieve always the same speed?

Comment: I wouldn't normally up-vote a question like this but I did to balance the misguided down vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Link your duration to the pixels you are having to move.

The duration in your code is locked at `500`. If I get the amount of pixels that have to be moved in either direction and multiply it by some milliseconds you can get a set speed at which the page will scroll.

Replace this:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
```

With this:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 
    Math.abs(window.scrollY - $(this.hash).offset().top) * 10);
```

Edit the `10` above to increase or decrease the duration.

Comment: Thank You very much! This answer is perfect for a noob like me and works great.

Comment: `Math.pow(Math.abs(window.scrollY - $(this.hash).offset().top),2/3)*5)` gives you much better scroll on large scale of height, in my case more than 60k pixels ...